# Recommend an Open Source .NET Statistics Library

Tags: .net, math, open-source, statistics

I need to calculate averages, standard deviations, medians etc for a bunch of numerical data. Is there a good open source .NET library I can use? I have found NMath but it is not free and may be overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this on the CodeProject website.  It looks like a good C# class for handling most of the basic statistical functions.

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csstatistics.aspx

Comment: Yuck! Why do some people persist in writing method/class name in lowercase and not PascalCase; it just makes the code look wrong.

Answer (score 17):

You have to be careful. There are several ways to compute standard deviation that would give the same answer if floating point arithmetic were perfect.  They're all accurate for some data sets, but some are far better than others under some circumstances.

The method I've seen proposed here is the one that is most likely to give bad answers. I used it myself until it crashed on me.

See [Comparing three methods of computing standard deviation](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/).

Answer (score 8):

How about http://ilnumerics.net/ or http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ (merge from http://www.codeplex.com/dnAnalytics)

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [MathNet](http://mathnet.opensourcedotnet.info/About.aspx)  it is not specifically for statistics, but there might be useful functionality for what you want

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Maths.Common](http://commons.apache.org/math/download_math.cgi)  and run it through [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html).

Answer (score 3):

I decided it was quicker to write my own, that just did what I needed. Here's the code...

```
/// <summary>
/// Very basic statistical analysis routines
/// </summary>
public class Statistics
{
    List<double> numbers;
    public double Sum { get; private set; }
    public double Min { get; private set; }
    public double Max { get; private set; }
    double sumOfSquares;

    public Statistics()
    {
        numbers = new List<double>();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return numbers.Count; }
    }

    public void Add(double number)
    {
        if(Count == 0)
        {
            Min = Max = number;
        }
        numbers.Add(number);
        Sum += number;
        sumOfSquares += number * number;
        Min = Math.Min(Min,number);
        Max = Math.Max(Max,number);            
    }

    public double Average
    {
        get { return Sum / Count; }
    }

    public double StandardDeviation
    {
        get { return Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquares / Count - (Average * Average)); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A simplistic implementation of Median
    /// Returns the middle number if there is an odd number of elements (correct)
    /// Returns the number after the midpoint if there is an even number of elements
    /// Sorts the list on every call, so should be optimised for performance if planning
    /// to call lots of times
    /// </summary>
    public double Median
    {
        get
        {
            if (numbers.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't calculate the median with no data");
            numbers.Sort();
            int middleIndex = (Count) / 2;
            return numbers[middleIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That algorithm works in theory, and often works in practice. But see this post for an example of where that algorithm can fail. http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/

Comment: @JohnD.Cook thanks for the useful information. For the data I was using, the method above works fine. How about posting us a short C# sample with your recommended algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

[AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com) has AForge.Math namespace, providing some basic statistics functions: Histogram, mean, median, stddev, entropy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do some one-off number crunching, a spreadsheet is far and away your best tool.  It's trivial to spit out a simple CSV file from C#, which you can then load up in Excel (or whatever):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.csv", false, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            WriteCsvLine(sw, new List<string>() { "Name", "Length", "LastWrite" });

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(".");
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                List<string> columns = new List<string>();
                columns.Add(fi.Name.Replace(",", "<comma>"));
                columns.Add(fi.Length.ToString());
                columns.Add(fi.LastWriteTime.Ticks.ToString());

                WriteCsvLine(sw, columns);
            }
        }
    }

    static void WriteCsvLine(StreamWriter sw, List<string> columns)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columns.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Then you can just 'start excel output.csv' and use functions like "=MEDIAN(B:B)", "=AVERAGE(B:B)", "=STDEV(B:B)".  You get charts, histograms (if you install the analysis pack), etc.

The above doesn't handle everything; generalized CSV files are more complex than you might think.  But it's "good enough" for much of the analysis I do.