# What is a good statistical math package for .Net?

Tags: c#, math, statistics

I am looking for a library that does advanced math, statistics, statistical distribution, etc..

Currently I am looking for something that does binomial and poisson distribution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[MathDotNet](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) should have the functions you are looking for, although it may be a bit of overkill depending on how much functionality you need.
It offers:

- Bernoulli
- Beta
- Binomial
- Categorical
- Cauchy
- Chi
- Chi Square
- Continuous Uniform
- Conway Maxwell Poisson
- Dirichlet
- Discrete Uniform
- Erlang
- Exponential
- etc.... (about 3x more on the list)

For a complete list see [this page](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/index.htm).

Answer (score 14):

.NET Framework languages C#, F# and VB.NET

[ILNumerics.Net](http://ilnumerics.net/) high performance, typesafe numerical array classes and functions for general math, FFT and linear algebra, aims .NET/mono, 32&64 bit, script-like syntax in C#, 2D & 3D plot controls, efficient memory management

[IMSL Numerical Libraries](http://www.roguewave.com/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/.net-library.aspx) for .NET is a set of mathematical, statistical, data mining, financial and charting classes written in C#.

[Measurement Studio](http://www.ni.com/mstudio/) is an integrated suite UI controls and class libraries for use in developing test and measurement applications. The analysis class libraries provide various digital signal processing, signal filtering, signal generation, peak detection, and other general mathematical functionality.

[NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/) by CenterSpace Software: numerical component libraries for the .NET platform, including signal processing (FFT) classes, a linear algebra (LAPACK & BLAS) framework, and a statistics package.

[suanshu.net](http://numericalmethod.com/blog/suanshu/) by Numerical Method Inc.: is a large collection of numerical algorithms including linear algebra, (advanced) optimization, interpolation, Markov model, principal component analysis, time series analysis, hypothesis testing, regressions, statistics, ordinary and partial differential equation solvers, and suanshu.
NLinear is a generic linear algebra toolkit in C# compatible with Silverlight.

Answer (score 5):

[Math.NET Numerics](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/) is a pretty good open source library for .NET. According to its site:

> Numerics is the numerical foundation of the Math.NET project, aiming to provide methods and algorithms for numerical computations in science, engineering and every day use. Covered topics include special functions, linear algebra, probability models, random numbers, interpolation, integral transforms and more.

If commercial library is an acceptable choice for you there are several of them I can recommend.

1. [NMath Stats](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath-stats/) from [CenterSpace Software](http://www.centerspace.net/) is a good choice. This library is specially designed for statistical computing and it is promised to be very efficient.
2. [FinMath](https://rtmath.net/products/finmath/) is rather new but promising library. It contains a lot of statistical distributions, routines for computing descriptive statistics, a few variants of least squares data fitting algorithms (OLS, GLS etc.), PCA, ICA and other implementations of various algorithms and techniques.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

- [Extreme Optimization](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/), The Extreme Optimization Numerical Libraries for .NET are a collection of general-purpose mathematical and **statistical** classes built for the Microsoft .NET framework.
- [FoundaStat](http://www.foundasoft.com/) (exist a free version) , is a statistical library for Microsoft .NET platform. FoundaStat provides statistical computation capabilities to all .NET software products. It includes classes that provide capabilities to interface with the various data format, calculating descriptive statistics, correlation analysis, statistical inferences, ANOVA, and multiple regression analysis.

Other links

[Recommend an Open Source .NET Statistics Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139384/recommend-an-open-source-net-statistics-library)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [CenterSpace Software's](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/stats/) .NET stats package.  We have binomial and poisson distributions, their CDF, and inverses (which can be a pain to accurately calculate.).

The Stats package offers high performance classes for:

1. Clustering / K-Means clustering
2. A wide variety of probability distributions and CDF's and inverse CDF's - including    specifically binomial and poisson.
3. Hypothesis Testing.
4. Non-negative matrix factorization.
5. Partial Least Squares.
6. Regression (Linear, Anova, QR, SVD, and more).
7. Principle Component Analysis.

Paul

[CenterSpace Software](http://Centerspace.net)