# Does Microsoft Have a Language Similar to R?

Tags: c#, r, data-analysis

As I understand there are languages that are excellent for mathematics, statistics and analysis.

I'm getting into Data Science, and the language that keeps popping up is R. Does Microsoft have a language similar to R? I come from a C# background. I develop applications in C#, so it would be nice to have a language similar to R that I can use in my current C# projects for data science and data analysis related tasks.

Does such a language exist?

Comment: I haven't heard of anything resembling "R#", but eh.  That seems the most obvious name (even though it semi-clashes with "Resharper", a VS add-in).

Comment: R can call cpp.  Dunno specifically about c#.  But why on earth are you looking for a Redmond-based language?

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for a Redmond-based language. I'm looking for a language, ideally a Microsoft language, that is suitable for Data Analysis and Mathematics.

Comment: There's always automation with Excel... :)

Comment: @cHao I'd rather not go backwards lol. I'll be dealing with huge datasets that often contains mixed data. I need a language well suited to data analysis - ideally without having to learn a new one (such as learning R) - to correlate the data.

Comment: I don't know if @cHao is being sarcastic, but Excel is not the best tool for harcore data analysis. I also come from a Java/C# background and I'm now an R user. I suggest you dive in as soon as possible - R is great!

Comment: You're aware that using *any other language* to work with the data, will by definition involve learning another language, right?  I'd suggest you just suck it up and learn R.  At the very least, you'll be using a language that a not-insignificant number of other people use, know, and most importantly, can help you with when/if you have trouble.

Comment: I don't know why you are specifically for a Microsoft language, but as you have a programming background it shouldn't be to hard to learn R. I have no programming background and was able to use R within 2 months. It's a great language for data analysis and there is an active community around it (among others over here @ SO).

Comment: A more relevant question/search target might be for convenient R <-> C# pipelines and interfaces ...

Comment: An alternative to R might be Python with the Numpy, Scipy & Pandas libraries.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS: It was about 90% sarcasm.  Excel can do pretty charts and stuff, and can be useful for little bits of data, but yeah -- probably not the best choice for data sets over a few thousand rows in any case.

Comment: @Jaap I think it's a bit different. Coming to R from another programming language may present a few challenges that wouldn't come up otherwise. One of those in the concept of vectorization.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS given that MatLab, c, python, and FSM knows which others all support vectorization, your comment is a bit slack.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry. I come from a Java/C#/Visual Basic background. I didn't know these other programming languages used vectorization.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557507/what-is-a-good-statistical-math-package-for-net

Comment: Your question is very broad. If you want the benefits of R you will need to learn a bit. To keep your C# assets I suggest you look at interop with http://rdotnet.codeplex.com and http://rclr.codeplex.com (formerly http://r2clr.codeplex.com). There are SO posts with tags R, C# and/or .NET that give more detailed answers some references to these libraries, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410528/calling-net-c-from-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS is the 800 lb gorilla in that market, but it's expensive and it's C# integration is limited to using C# to drive the SAS system (basically tell SAS to process a file, then output the results, then read those results).  As already mentioned in the comments R has C++ bindings, which can be used via interop in C#.  MS supplies F# which can be very useful for that sort of work (and interfaces naturally to C#).  One place to look is http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/ they always have lots of stuff going on and might provide something that would be useful.  Also LINQ in C# provides some primitive functionality (sums, averages, that sort of thing) and can be easily extended.