# Calculate percentile from t-score in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, math, statistics

Is it possible to calculate the percentile from a T-score in .NET? How would you do it?

For example, I received a T-score of 60, which according to the table below gives a percentile of 84.

Is there a formula to convert from T-score to percentile? Or do I always need to use this table to look it up?

[image]

Comment: Maybe one of these answers will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246348/is-there-a-net-statistics-library-with-t-tests-and-p-values

Comment: Cross posting is frowned upon.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142716/calculate-percentile-from-t-score

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Springer article on T-Score](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-79948-3_1254)

> T scores have a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of 10. Standard z scores can be converted to T scores using the formula below.
>
> `T=10∗z+50`

So using [MathNet.Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) package you can simply do

```cs
    static double PercintileFromTScore(double tScore)
    {
        var normalDistribution = new MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal(50, 10); // shoulbe be shorten "using" in the real life
        return normalDistribution.CumulativeDistribution(tScore);
    }
```

This seems to produce results identical to the table you provided.